# Android toolbar ficando atras da topbar

Tags: android, android-layout

O que pode estar ocorrendo, a toolbar ta ficando atras do topbar como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso ta ocorrendo nas versões
4.4.2 e 4.1.1

Comment: Coloque um pouco de código.

Comment: Assim como o Pablo, recomendo colocar o layout xml dessa `Activity`. Acredito que esteja usando um `NavigationView` e o atributo `fitsSystemWindows` que não está sendo usado nos filhos da raiz.